# Store Terraform secret in Azure DevOps library

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, secret-key

I have a few secrets used by a provider of Terraform that I would like to store in an Azure DevOps Library (instead of storing them in git...).
I created a library and called my variables TF_VAR_XXX.

The library is called in the pipeline with the following code:

```
stages:
  - stage: Deploy_1
  pool: "our_pool"
  variables:
    - group: shared
```

Terraform pick ups all my variables correctly and everything works very well when my variables are set as plain text variable in the library.

As soon as I set the variables as Secret in the Azure DevOps library, Terraform does not find these values anymore:

```
The root module input variable "SPN_XXX_CLIENT_SECRET" is not set, 
and has no default value. Use a -var or -var-file command line argument 
to provide a value for this variable.
```

Any ideas on this issue?

Thank you for your time! :)

Comment: Can you provide some code from your pipeline? How you use the variable group and the variables notation on the pipeline?

Comment: I updated my question with this detail. Thank you

Comment: Any other idea on this issue?